# Boost signals2 not getting compiled

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors

When I just add an header `#include <boost/signals2.hpp>` in VS

I am getting following error even though it's able to find the header.

```
1>signals.cpp
1>c:\apps\mvs15\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\memory(53): error C4996: 'std::uninitialized_copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate': Call to 'std::uninitialized_copy' with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
1>c:\apps\mvs15\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\memory(53): note: see declaration of 'std::uninitialized_copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate'
1>c:\boost_1_69_0\boost\signals2\detail\auto_buffer.hpp(191): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_FwdIt *std::uninitialized_copy<I,boost::shared_ptr<void>*>(_InIt,_InIt,_FwdIt)' being compiled
```

I am not able to fix this. But my `Boost.Asio` library headers work fine and code is compilable. So I think there is not issue with boost installation.

Edit1: I downloaded windows prebuild binaries from [boost](https://www.boost.org/users/download/) website and installed. I am using VS 2017. I have added the path to library, headers in properties as follows.

> Configuration Properties->Linked->General->Additional Library
>   Directories as C:\boost_1_69_0\lib64-msvc-14.1;
>
> Configuration Properties->Include Directories added additional folder
>   C:\boost_1_69_0;

Edit2: Issue got resolved by adding -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in

> Configuration Properties->C/C++->Command Line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are compiling on windows, using VS 2017.

C4996 is actually a warning ([compiler warning C4996](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4996?view=vs-2017))  , not error, so you have probably activated option to treat all warnings as errors. To check, right click on target properties, then expand "C/C++", and go to General properties, as shown on the following snapshots:

[image]

[image]

If my assumptions are wrong, add necessary information (compiler/os/ how did you obtain boost, did it compile correctly, ....), so we can find better answer.

EDIT:
since you stated that you didn't change compile options, you should search source code for [#pragma warninng(error:....)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=vs-2017) somewhere in your source code.

Comment: This is not the issue. It's set as No only.